# Facebook (and Google) login for 2 apps on the same Firebase project

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am currently building a mobile solution that will have an Uber-like model (one app for stores and one app for customers).

Right now I am developing the Android apps using Flutter, but it is possible that an iOS version will be released as the product grows. Since the business logic is quite simple I am implementing the backend in a serverless way through Firebase services.

I will have some stores thumbnails stored in Firebase Storage, those thumbnails must be also accesed from customer's application. I struggled with the first issue: how do I implement Firebase login (Facebook, Google and Email/password) given that I will put all apps on the same Firebase Project.

The issue arises because Facebook login needs to be provided an api secret and key, but I will end up having 2 of these (one for each Android app and maybe 2 more in the future for the ios apps).

Comment: 1. you can try to add the type of user to the firebasestore and save it in the users collection, once the app opens you can check the type and decide to show what where

Comment: But how can I even add the app secret to the Firebase authentication method, which has project scope (it is one app secret per Facebook app and I have one app for every Android app).